# Bluetooth not showing on Dell inspiron 14r N4010 running linux mint 17.2

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, bluetooth

Wifi works fine, but when I try to use bluetooth, it says "No bluetooth adapters found". I have Bluetooth turned on in the BIOS, and I know that my wireless card supports Bluetooth.Here's my laptop's model: http://www.pcworld.com/product/552981/inspiron-14r-notebook.html

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8086:0188 Intel Corp. WiMAX Connection 2400m  
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:641d Microdia 1.3 MPixel Integrated Webcam  
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 413c:8162 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Touchpad  

[Synaptics] 

Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:8161 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Keyboard  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
[    0.248151] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored  
[    0.265149] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness  
[   12.290100] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19  
[   12.290129] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized  
[   12.290140] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized  
[   12.290144] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized  
[   12.290157] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized  
[   12.319209] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3  
[   12.319212] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast  
[   12.319222] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized  
[   12.390067] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized  
[   12.390085] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized  
[   12.390095] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11  
[   12.782452] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 41.28.5.1 build 33926 op_mode iwldvm  
[   17.925009] i2400m_usb 2-1.5:1.0: firmware interface version 9.3.2  
Linux Digv2 3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 8 09:43:57 UTC   2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux  
0: phy0: Wireless LAN  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no  
1: i2400m-usb:2-1.5:1.0: WiMAX  
    Soft blocked: yes  
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/232788/edit) your question to add terminal results for `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'; uname -a; rfkill list all` Thanks

Comment: updated it, is this what you wanted?

Comment: Do you know the model of the Dell bluetooth module that is installed?  Are you dual boot with Windows?

Comment: I do no have it dual booted.  
Standard Dell™ Wireless 365 Bluetooth® Internal (2.1+EDR) mini-card

Comment: There is a post on linux mint forums that was solved after using windows and a program from dell that enabled the bluetooth

Comment: do you have a link?

Comment: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=190888#p1073602